# Using jdbi library with multiple databases in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbi

I have a spring boot application using jdbi library.

But now I have to get or save data from or to different databases.

For example I need to use jdbi to query data from an external Oracle database and then save the partial data in a postgres database within the app.

I know you can setup two different data sources using spring data or jpa. But is there any way we can setup different databases using jdbi library? Any examples?